# Is there a performance penalty for creating a closure vs writing a function in swift?

Tags: swift, function, performance, closures

Is there a performance penalty for creating and using a closure vs a normal function?
See example below:

using a closure:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
let doubler: (Int) -> Int = {
    $0 * 2
}
array.map {
    doubler($0)
}
```

using a function

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
array.map { double($0) }
...
func double(_ num: Int) -> Int {
     return num * 2
}
```

which one would be faster and why?
Thanks in advance?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. They are exactly the same.

Comment: as in grammatically the same or compiled down-wise the same?  on what do you base this? do you have any reference where I can double check?

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance penalties, because global and nested functions are special cases of closures.

Comment: thanks! surely grammatically, but I suspect they are treated differently by the compiler... do you have any source to back your claim?

Comment: @serotonino https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/closures/